# create a list of values in a column in pandas based on values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe containing 3 columns. I want to get the value in first column corresponding to last entry in second column and the the value in first column whose their associated values in second column have at least 8 difference with the last entry of second column and put them in a list. Since `18` is the reference, I want to have its associated value from col1 in the list and have a data frame in the output. I am trying to figure out how I can do this in pandas.

```
col1  col2   col3
 a      0      1
 b      2      1
 c      13     1
 d      18     1
```

the output that i want is:

```
    col1   col3
 [d, b, a]  1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the way I interpreted your question `d` should not be included. This is since `18 - 18 = 0 < 8`

Regardless, I took a three step approach to this problem.

```
# Get the desired reference value
last_entry = df.iloc[-1][col2]

# Select only rows whose difference is at least 8 
# Or the case where it is the last entry 
qry = "{ref}-col2 >= 8 or index=={idx}".format(ref=last_entry, idx=len(df)-1)
diff_gt_8 = df.query(qry) 

# For each value of col3 get a list of values of col1 and convert to DataFrame
pd.DataFrame( diff_gt_8.groupby(col3)[col1].apply(list) )
```

To compare it to your previous value:

```
df[(df[col2] - df[col2].shift(1)) < 12]
```

Note that `df[col2].shift(1)` returns a series with all rows down by 1. So we can compare a row in `df[col2]` to its previous row.
The first value will never be included since it is NaN (not a number).

**UPDATE**

If I've understood your new question correctly, this is what you want.

```
last_two_rows = df.iloc[-2:, :] # Select last two rows
if (last_two_rows.iloc[-1][col2] - last_two_rows.iloc[-2][col2]) < 12:
    last_two_rows[col1].iloc[-2] = np.nan
last_two_rows[[col1]]
```

Comment: thanks for solution but I do need `d` not because of the `8` difference, because it is the reference and i want its corresponding value to be included in list as well!

Comment: Hi, I have updated the solution by including the last row.

Comment: Is there any way to use df.query() for comparing the last entry of second column to ONLY its previous value and see if is less than a specific value, change the corresponding value to `nan` and make the list like `[d, 'nan']`?

Comment: I tried this `qry = "{ref} - {refer} < 12 ".format(ref=last_entry, refer=last_to_sec)` `df.query(qry)` and I got this error `KeyError: u'the label [True] is not in the [index]'
`

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your new question.
Please accept my answer if it works, thanks!

Comment: the new addition part is not what i want. I want the comparison of two last entries in `second` column, see if less than a specific value. if so, grab the two last entries of corresponding values in `First` column and change the second to last entry of FIRST column to `nan`.The desired output is in the dataframe format with the `first` column with the value [d, 'nan']